# add numbers using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi Guys simple question (but failed to do this **:(** ). Just want to add all the numbers in `<li>`

PLeae check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/6j0xq49v/1/

Or you can check my code below

```
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="total"><div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('button').click(function(){
var thistext = 0;
$('ul li').each(function(){
    thistext = $(this).text();
    thistext += parseInt(thistext)
    alert(thistext)
})
})
```

Please help me guys Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning both the sum and each individual value to `thistext`. Try this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var thistext = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    thistext += parseInt($(this).text());
    alert(thistext);
  });
  $('.total').text(thistext);
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m81xcp0/

**UPDATE**

If you need to account for the case where not all `li` elements contain numbers:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  var thistext = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (isNaN(text)) { return; }
    thistext += parseInt(text);
    alert(thistext);
  });
  $('.total').text(thistext);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6m81xcp0/1/

Comment: thanks for help .. but one more question .. if there is no number some <li> there is string then how to handle it for ur reff please check fiddle here 
http://jsfiddle.net/6j0xq49v/2/

Comment: You can check whether the text value is a number by calling `isNaN`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
thistext = $(this).text();
```

and use this way:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var thistext = 0;
  $('ul li').each(function(a, v) {
     thistext += (+v.textContent); // parsing to number if prepend with +
  });
  $('.total').text(thistext);
  console.log(thistext);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<button>Click</button>
<div class="total">
  <div>
```